# Nginx rewrite specific file only

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

My url looks like this:

```
http://site.ru/web/index.php?r=api%2Finit&user_id=1&extension_id=test
```

And I want rewrite it using Nginx to:

```
http://site.ru/api/v1/?action=init&user_id=1&bot_extension_id=test
```

That is, rewriting `index.php?r=api` only, without touching other values for `r`.

This is what I've tried, it isn't working though

```
location / {
    rewrite /web/index.php?r=api%2F(.*?) /api/v1/?action=$1;
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```